# Work and energy in a free body diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, free-body-diagram

> [image: 1]
>
> A body at O is exerted by forces as shown in FIGURE 1. As a result, it moves 4 cm parallel to the net force exerted.
>
> (i) Determine the net force exerted on the body.
>
> (ii) Find the work done on the body.

I trying...

[image]

I'm stuck here. can you help me solve this?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint:  Find the resultant force in the $x$ direction, then the resultant force in the $y$ direction.

Then re-draw the force diagram with just those two forces and have a think about it...